# Unable to get user_likes on my own Facebook user account via the Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'm using the current version 2.3 of the Facebook Graph API. I am using the Graph API explorer. I generated an access token for user_likes in the API explorer and granted the API explorer application those rights.

However, when I type:

```
me?fields=user_likes
```

in the Url textbox and submit it, I get just the public profile and not the user likes.

[image]

I also do not get any errors.

When I try this in code using an access token granted to my ASP.NET MVC web application (in sandbox mode), I get an exception that says:

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #100) (#100) 
Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_likes) on node type (User) 
at 
Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags) 
at 
Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) 
at 
Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) at 
Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters) 
at 
Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path) 
at 
OAuthFacebookExample.Controllers.HomeController.FacebookCallback() 
in 
c:\temp\OAuth\rnd\OAuthFacebookExample\OAuthFacebookExample\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
```

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
dynamic userInfo = 
 client.Get("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,user_likes");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

me?user_likes is not a valid endpoint. I think you wanted to use me?fields=user_likes which is also invalid (there is no field called user_likes)

Please check out Facebook docs for user likes:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

As you can see, the endpoint you want to call is me/likes.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'd made a typo in the original post. I'd actually typed `/me?fields=user_likes` but as you rightly pointed out, that too is an invalid scope or field value. Apparently, the right field name is just `likes`, which gives me the data I want.